# Why was my answer deleted for copying content?

Tags: support, answers, flagging

[Confusing with 12 hive concept](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42982/confusing-with-12-hive-concept)

I dont understand why my answer was deleted? The comment says it was copied from this: http://grounding.co.za/blogs/brett/archive/2008/03.aspx

Yet I can only see that the folder names are in the same order and nothing else, so how is that plagarism?

It was flagged by the creator of the post due to him getting upset with me downvoting three of his posts. I think those downvotes were fair and honest, so I dont see why I should be punished for it! If you could kindly take the time to read over those posts you'll see for yourselves why I downvoted!

I was told the first time, so I removed it and edited it, and then it got removed the second time. But it was written in my own words this time. I cant change the folder names now can I?

I hope I can get some insight into this!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: In the future, I would also strongly encourage you to leave a comment offering some *friendly, constructive advice* on how the answer could be improved in addition to downvoting. Lets make our goal to help others and improve the site. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what happened, which I hope will help you: Your original post was identical to the blog post in the link. I deleted it and contacted you directly in order to give you a chance to respond, but you did not. You then deleted the content of the original post and created a new post which was similar but has a few words switched around and still has a substantial amount of copied content - I am afraid it looked identical to me and I thought you had re-posted the original one (my mistake). I deleted it and posted a comment for you in case you didn't get the direct message.

If you decide to improve a post in response to a moderator suggestion it is probably better to edit the original post so that the moderator can see what you have changed, or at least leave a comment to explain what you have done.

Copying content verbatim from a blog or website is plagiarism. It is permissible to paraphrase or express ideas in your own words, or to quote small sections (with attribution) as "fair use". The best approach is to use other sources as your own reference material but to write answers in your own words, and that means more than just switching a few words around while leaving the content substantially the same as the original.

I hope that helps you understand why I deleted this post. Please help us by taking care not to put content on our site that could get us into trouble. If you keep adding great, original, content your reputation will increase and you won't need to worry about the odd downvote, even though it is frustrating. When I first contributed to StackOverflow a user downvoted all answers because they didn't like SharePoint and I ended up with a negative reputation!

Comment: I guess copying the content from any blogs is not considered as "Copied" if I mention the original source from where I am took the code. Because somewhere that code helped me so I can suggest that code. Right?